# How to emit onDropped in QML drag n drop example?

Tags: application-development, qt, qml

In the qml documentation there is a [drag'n'drop example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-drag.html#drop-method):

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    width: 200; height: 200

    DropArea {
        x: 75; y: 75
        width: 50; height: 50

        onDropped: console.log("dropped")
        onEntered: console.log("entered")

        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "green"

            visible: parent.containsDrag
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        x: 10; y: 10
        width: 20; height: 20
        color: "red"

        Drag.active: dragArea.drag.active
        Drag.hotSpot.x: 10
        Drag.hotSpot.y: 10

        MouseArea {
            id: dragArea
            anchors.fill: parent

            drag.target: parent
        }
    }
}
```

I have added the two lines with "onDropped" and "onEntered". 
While "onEntered" is triggered by dragging the small rectangle, I can not make the "onDropped" to trigger.

What do I have to do to make it trigger?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apparently a drop needs to be generated explicitly by calling the [drop() method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-drag.html#drop-method) on the [Drag](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-drag.html) object

Try adding this line inside of the `MouseArea`, just above `drag.target: parent`

```
onReleased: parent.Drag.drop()
```