# Cannot detect if a MouseArea is over a GridView item

Tags: ubuntu-touch, qt, qml, qt-creator, javascript

*This question is not specific for the Ubuntu platform, but as I am developing an Ubuntu Touch app, I'd like to ask first here.*

I have a list of UbuntuShapes arranged in a GridView - generated from a ListModel object - and a Rectangle object with a MouseArea that I can drag all around the application's MainView. What I want to do is that if the mouse releases the rectangle over an UbuntuShape, it executes an action associated with that one UbuntuShape.

Considering that:

- I cannot assign an ID to each object generated by a ListView/GridView's delegate
- I cannot use a JavaScript function as an argument for a new ListElement
- I cannot dynamically add items to a Flickable/GridView and make them scrollable
- I cannot use a MouseArea's `entered` signal if it is under another MouseArea

how could I detect if the rectangle is over an specific UbuntuShape from the GridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you should be using Drag and Drop in addition to just MouseArea, as shown in https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/apps/qml/current/QtQuick.Drag/

Comment: I'm having trouble using the onDropped signal. However, seems like this is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: This fixed the onDropped problem, BTW! http://askubuntu.com/questions/301145/how-to-emit-ondropped-in-qml-drag-n-drop-example